# PlayPlugin onApplicationStart does not work

Tags: java, module, playframework

I try to write a small playframework-module and a plugin in it, and want be sure that it will start when I'm starting up the application.

**[myapp] -- uses --> [registration(module)].[plugin(RegistrtionPlugin)]**

There is my plugin class I've put to /src/play/modules/registration int he module source

```
public class RegistrationPlugin extends PlayPlugin {
    public void onApplicationStart() {
        Logger.info("Yeeha, firstmodule started");
    }
}
```

I have dependency to this module form my application, when i do play deps - it shows me that everything good. Or when i type in console in my app-home folder: play registration:hello - it replies me 'Hello' back.

I've got this code from PlayFramework Cook book (chapter 5), but can not make it working as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a play.plugins file to your module src folder configuring the RegistrationPlugin plugin?

The play.plugins of e.g. the spring plugins looks like this:

```
1000:play.modules.spring.SpringPlugin
```

You might also take a deeper look at the [spring plugin](https://github.com/pepite/Play--framework-Spring-module):

At last before the module can be used following command has to be executed:

```
play build-module
```

Comment: yes, i did... I was adding everything while reading that chapter. but does not work. but I do not use spring in this simple app, bwt.

Comment: there are a few other steps I can image you might have missed. Have you e.g. forgot to run play build-module? (have updated my description). If not can you also paste your dependency.yml configuration? There might be the error.

Comment: i did it. but i had not any new files in /lib directory of my app in result, like it was described in the book. I had only zip file in /disrt direcotry in the module.

Comment: Well I do not know what it is exactly written in the book. However there is no need that a library is added to the lib. However there should be a text file in the modules folder pointing to your module. If there isn't one there might be an error in your dependency.yml. Or do you use the application.conf file to configure your module? Would be good to have a look at the configuration (dependency.yml or application.conf) you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your RegistrationPlugin to regular /app folder

and don't forget to include path to plugin in /src/play.plugins file.

f.e. 
    1000:RegistrationPlugin

if RegistrationPlugin is in default package